# Acelerar resultado cURL

Tags: curl

Estoy calculando la disponibilidad de una página mediante cURL y me encuentro que con "I" puedo llegar a tardar mas de 7 segundos en recuperar el resultado mientras que con "i" es inmediato.

```
curl -I ${URL}

curl -i ${URL}
```

Hay forma de mejorar los tiempos de respuesta al usar "I" ?

gracias!

Answer (score 0):

He realizado una docena de pruebas comparando los parámetros -i y -I en diferentes URL y no obtengo tiempos tan lentos como los que indicas.

Si  con -i te funciona correctamente y solo necesitas el valor de un encabezado, pasa el resultado de curl por un pipe y hazle un grep:

```
curl -is https://es.stackoverflow.com | grep "content-length"
```

Si lo que necesitas es el código de respuesta puedes utilizar head.

```
curl -is https://es.stackoverflow.com | head -1
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si. Es lo que estoy haciendo. un grep con el string que me interesa capturar. Me extraño el comportamiento entre ambos...

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta añadiendo las URLs con las que obtienes esos tiempos? Sería de gran utilidad para poder comparar resultados en base a las mismas URLs.